# MySQL is too smart about accented characters

Tags: mysql, diacritics, cjk

I guess, normally people would be aiming to make their programme behave like this, but in my case this is completely opposite from what I want.

Somehow, my MySQL database is able to read different accented characters as identical. For instance, `shī`, `shí`, `shǐ`, `shì` and `shi` are all the same thing to it. When I search for one, I’ll get the others as well. Proofpic:

[image: smart SQL]

This is not what I want, since for me those values are very different. Basically, the query on the pic must return empty rows, because there is no a single entry in that table with `shi` (without an accent).

My tables type is InnoDB, collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I get dual results from mysql query when using international charachters, i.e Å/Ä=A & Ö=O,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018950/i-get-dual-results-from-mysql-query-when-using-international-charachters-i-e-a-a)

Comment: Sounds like the best approach would be that you create your own collation and specify comparison rules, or try out collations that aren't utf8_general_ci. Personally, I've no idea which collation would suit you so let's hope someone with more knowledge will suggest a different collation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `utf8_bin` collation. You don't have to change collation of entire column, you can just use it on per query basis

```
WHERE `pinyin` = 'shi' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

You can also experiment with different collations which might work better for you (`utf8_bin` works on binery level, so even if two unicode characters with different byte codes are the same, it will see them as different).

Comment: Thanks, it works when I add `COLLATE utf8_bin` to my query. However, if I change the collation of the table itself and run my first query (without the collation definition), it still displays all different accented characters.

Comment: Are you changing a collation of the table, or of specific column? Remember, a collation of table is just the default collation that will be used if any new columns are added.

Comment: Right! Of course, I was only changing the table collation, not the column collation. It all works great now. Thank you.